# Как на Css на GIF поставить цветную немного прозрачную плёнку?

Tags: css

```
background-image: url(https://i.gifer.com/3wmY.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Сейчас gif анимация стоит вот так,хочу сверху цветную плёнку накинуть чтобы сливался с цветом сайта,но не могу

Comment: попробуйте [составной background](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp) можно взять изображение поверху наложить цвет или градиент, поверху еще что то... и все в одном свойстве

Comment: А вот в [этой статье](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/) готовый код

Answer (score 0):

Через `:before` или `:after` самый простой вариант:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://i.gifer.com/3wmY.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.image:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(241, 178, 236, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```